# How to add multiple checkboxes in woocommerce custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding custom fields in woo commerce it is adding one checkbox but I want More checkboxes say 20.

My working code for one checkbox is :

```
function woocommerce_general_product_data_custom_field() 
{

    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
                'id' => 'product_checkbox',
                'wrapper_class' => 'checkbox_class',
                'label' => __('Select Country :', 'woocommerce' ),
                'description' => __( 'India', 'woocommerce' )
            ),  
        );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This code snippet create a single checkbox of Country
but I wants 30 checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Would a drop down list not provide a cleaner solution for this? I think 30 check boxes would create an awful lot of clutter